# Keeping some selected options after submitting form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on the following:

I've created a php-page to add works from composers to CDs in a database. It's a combination of two forms and looks like this:

> 1st form:
>
> Composer : [drop down list] : Select

Some blank space

> 2nd form:
>
> Title : [drop down list]
>
> Track number : [empty varchar field]
>
> Work : [drop down list]
>
> some other fields

Process button

After selecting a name in the first block (posting to `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`) I stay on the same page, that name is shown in the blank space in between and the drop down lists are populated with only CD titles and works of the selected composer.

I can then select from the lists and enter other data in the other fields. Hitting the process button posts the data from the second block to another page which will eventually send everything to a table in a MySQL database.

After that I send myself back to the first page with `header("Location: the_first_page.php")`

So far so good, but upon returning I would like the composer, title and work to be preselected. Now I'm sent to a blank page and have to start from scratch. I think I've seen some solution involving testing `$_POST['something']` against `<option value>` in a drop down list but I can't seem to make that work.

My question is: Is there a way to send `$_POST['Title']` and `$_POST['Work']` back to the first page somehow? Or is it better to split the two forms over seperate pages?

All help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sessions or the post data itself. For using the post data itself, the page where you send the request should be the same and include the script that will process it if there's some data like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  include "save.php";
  }

// More code...

?>
<select name = "a">
  <option <?php if ($_POST['a'] == "test")  echo "selected"; ?> value = "test">
  <option <?php if ($_POST['a'] == "testb") echo "selected"; ?> value = "testb">
</select>
```

Of course there are many more ways, but this is just a simple one to get you started. Things to know: you might want to change the variable $_POST and clean it up before using it. In this case it should be fine, but in `<input type = "text" value = "<?= $_POST['b']; ?>` name = "b">` you have a serious security issue.

For sanitizing the input, you want to sanitize it respect to what you expect. But also, as an EXTRA meassure, you normally want to strip everything that looks like a `<script>`, `onclick =""`, `' DROP TABLE users` and similar. It's not an easy subject, so I recommend you reading on it, mainly on the [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) which is relevant to showing the text back to the user. While it might seem too much work for this "simple case", it is useful in many more situations.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I went with the sessions option and all works. As for the $_POST variables, on the processing page I put them all through the following : `code`$Tracknr = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Tracknr', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW)); Hope that does enough tricks to make it safe(r).

Comment: For the text, you want to strip it depending on several things, including what you expect it to contain, where you are going to save it and where you expect to display it. Read the updated paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Use session variables and put conditions for them ... see [ $_SESSION ].